# Cannot make a simple query in MongoDB (AND OR NOT)

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Given a collection like:

```
> db.test.find({}, {_id:0})
{ "name" : "star wars I", "duration" : 120 }
{ "name" : "star wars II", "duration" : 125 }
{ "name" : "star wars III", "duration" : 135 }
{ "name" : "star wars IV", "duration" : 115 }
{ "name" : "star trek I", "duration" : 135 }
{ "name" : "star trek II", "duration" : 200 }
{ "name" : "alien", "duration" : 200 }
```

How can I make a query equivalent to this SQL statement?

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE (name LIKE '%star%' AND NOT name LIKE '%wars%') OR duration = 200
```

**Even with simpler queries I'm unable to get expected results, for example:**

This works as expected:

```
> db.test.find({ name: /star/i, name: /trek/i }, {_id:0})  
{ "name" : "star trek I", "duration" : 135 }  
{ "name" : "star trek II", "duration" : 200 }
```

But this one returns no results. Why?

```
> db.test.find({ name: /star/i, $not: {name: /trek/i} }, {_id:0})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You have to use the [$ne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/) operator at this point since [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/not/) is for negating other operators.</strike>

Edit: As stated by Peter in the comments $ne does not work here (because the regex is an operator). Just the order of your query was wrong.

```
> db.test.find({ name: /star/i, name: { $not: /trek/i } }, {_id:0})
```

The query for the given SQL should look something like this:

```
> db.test.find({$or:
    [
      { name: /star/i, name: { $not: /trek/i } },
      { duration: 200 }
    ]
  },{_id:0})
```

Comment: I get an error: `error: { "$err" : "invalid regular expression operator", "code" : 13454 }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 

`db.test.find({name: {$regex: /star/i , $not: /trek/i }}, {_id:0});`

Comment: Great! this solves the second question but... how should I do a query like the given SQL sentence? ((a and b) or c)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the query due to the fact that the word "star" is common to both "star war "  and "star trek " records.

This is a suggestion hope it helps

```
db.test.find({name:{$regex:/wars/,$nin:["trek"] }},{_id:0})
{ "name" : "star wars I", "duration" : 120 }
{ "name" : "star wars II", "duration" : 125 }
{ "name" : "star wars III", "duration" : 135 } 
{ "name" : "star wars IV", "duration" : 115 }
```

Comment: It's just an example. The query I want to do is far more complex. Thanks anyway :)